# Prove that if $n$ is a composite, then $2^n-1$ is composite.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

Not sure if I'm doing this correctly but this is what I've done:

Assume that $n$ is composite and suppose $2^n-1$ is a prime for $n \gt 2$.
Then, $2^n-1 = 2k$ for some $k \in \Bbb Z $, $\forall n$.  But this would be a contradiction since $n \gt 2$.  I'm not sure if this a correct proof.

EDIT: I realized that it's to prove $2^n - 1$ NOT $2^{n-1}$ so my attempt above is completely wrong.

Comment: Are you sure that the problem isn’t to prove that if $n$ is composite, then $2^n-1$ is composite?

Comment: @BrianM.Scott You're right it's $2^n - 1$.

Comment: So, in that case, my proof seems to be completely wrong.

Comment: If $n = ab$ where $a$ and $b$ are integers, try doing long division of $2^n-1$ by $2^a-1$, preferably expressing the numbers in base $2$.

Answer (score 5):

$$n=km\Longrightarrow 2^n-1=(2^k)^m-1=\left(2^k-1\right)\left((2^k)^{m-1}+(2^k)^{m-2}+\ldots+2^k+1\right)$$